# Aggregation Grouping by Two Fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a schema like the following:

```
Event : {
    eventType : Number,
    created : Date,
}
```

My end goal is to create a line graph for each `eventType` that shows how many of each event was posted daily.

I've never tried the MongoDB aggregation functions, so I'm a little confused on how to go about doing this. I read through the MongoDB aggregation documentation and my initial thought is to do two grouping and one project passes:

1. Group every event into a day
2. Group the results of this by `eventType`
3. Project these results so the output is in a nice format to graph.

So my output would look something like this (so I can put it on line graphs:

```
{
  [
    { 
        eventType: 0, 
        days : [ ISODate(2015-01-01), ISODate(2015-01-02), ISODate(2015-01-03) ], 
        totals: [ 0, 15, 3 ] 
    }, {
        eventType: 1, 
        days : [ ISODate(2015-01-01), ISODate(2015-01-02), ISODate(2015-01-03) ], 
        totals: [ 4, 5, 2 ] 
    }, {        
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure if conceptually that's correct, and I'm even less sure about the syntax this would require. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the basic idea here is to group twice, and you also want to make use of the [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/):

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "eventType":"$eventType",
            "date": { 
                "year": { "$year": "$created" },
                "month": { "$month": "$created" },
                "day": { "$dayOfMonth": "$created" }
            }
        },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.eventType",
        "days": { "$push": "$_id.date" },
        "totals": { "$push": "$total" }
    }}
])
```

Or you can use date math to return a timestamp value instead:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "eventType":"$eventType",
            "date": { 
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date(0) ] },
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date(0) ] },
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.eventType",
        "days": { "$push": "$_id.date" },
        "totals": { "$push": "$total" }
    }}
])
```

Personally, two arrays does not seem as readable as one does to me. So I prefer this:

```js
db.event.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "eventType":"$eventType",
            "date": { 
                "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date(0) ] },
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$subtract": [ "$created", new Date(0) ] },
                    ]}
                ]
            }
        },
        "total": { "$sum": 1 }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.eventType",
        "days": { 
            "$push": { 
                "date": "$_id.date", "total": "$total"
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Where each array index already contains all of the information.

Most graphing packages are really quite flexible when you really look at the documentation about supported data structures. It is a common MongoDB outuput request to format data in a particular way ( all in arrays ) for a "popular package", but that package actually does support the standard object lists as long as you configure it too. It's just that all the "basic examples" don't tell you otherwise.